# Angular 5 role based autherntication with @auth0/angular-jwt

Tags: javascript, authorization, roles, angular5, angular2-jwt

i need for advice in role based auth with `https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/tree/v1.0` JWT Interceptor.
How can i carry out "admin" role auth with Angular 5 ?

Now i have: after login server send back jwt token with user id in payload and using canActivate, my app check if token exist and then allow to enter secured sites.

```
@Injectable()
export class EnsureAuthenticated implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) {}
  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

and my secure rote :

```
export const SECURE_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [EnsureAuthenticated] },
    { path: 'homeadmin', component: HomeadminComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticatedAdmin] },
];
```

and after that I wanted to create something like that:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticatedAdmin implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) {}
  canActivate(): boolean {
    if ("in token is admin") {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

In this approach i need decode token with `https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode`
Do you think this is the correct approach? Please let me know if you have any better solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because JWT encode your data in payload section. If you want to get some property you need decode all payload.

When you analyze code in angular2-jwt you find method in JwtHelper class to get token expiration date. In its implementation find in third line that to extract expiration date you need first decode all token payload.

Example below from [angular2-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/blob/master/angular2-jwt.ts#L272)

```
public getTokenExpirationDate(token: string): Date {
  let decoded: any;
  decoded = this.decodeToken(token);

  if (!decoded.hasOwnProperty('exp')) {
    return null;
  }

  let date = new Date(0); // The 0 here is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
  date.setUTCSeconds(decoded.exp);

  return date;
}
```